# Angularjs: I want to print the result coming from the response object into individual elements in $http get response. Please see the code below

Tags: angularjs, json, http, get

This is the json:

```
 {"item":{"id":"3","firstName":"Eugene","lastName":"Lee","managerId":"1","title":"CFO","department":"Accounting","city":"Boston, MA","officePhone":"617-000-0003","cellPhone":"781-000-0003","email":"elee@fakemail.com","picture":"eugene_lee.jpg","managerFirstName":"James","managerLastName":"King","reportCount":"0"}}
```

Now with a $http get request I'm trying to get the response as

```
{"id":"3","firstName":"Eugene","lastName":"Lee","managerId":"1","title":"CFO","department":"Accounting","city":"Boston, MA","officePhone":"617-000-0003","cellPhone":"781-000-0003","email":"elee@fakemail.com","picture":"eugene_lee.jpg","managerFirstName":"James","managerLastName":"King","reportCount":"0"}
```

by using the following code

```
.controller('Detailing', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
$http.get("//localhost/directory/services/getemployee.php?id="+$stateParams.id)
.then(function(response) {
    $scope.employee = response.data.item;
})
});
```

It is giving me undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('Detailing', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
 $http.get("//localhost/directory/services/getemployee.php?id="+$stateParams.id)
.then(function(response) {
   $scope.employee = response.data; // Without item key
 })
});
```

The JSON does not contain the `item` key. Hence giving this error. Try the above

Comment: If I want to access the item how should I do it?

Comment: in the above http request you are fetching the single employee, not the all employees. hence you just get an object instead of array of objects. So no need to use item key.

Comment: I have done the above one. But when I access the scope using {{employee.firstName}} or {{employee.item.firstname}} it doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- Either your response is a `JSON string` instead of `JSON object`. Hence, when you try to get the item object from an `JSON string` it will gives you `undefined`.

[image]

- There is no item object in the response that you are getting from `$http.get` request.

[image]

**Solution :**

Use `JSON.parse()` to convert JSON String to JSON Object if the response that you are getting is `JSON string`.

**DEMO**

```js
var obj = '{"item":{"id":"3","firstName":"Eugene","lastName":"Lee","managerId":"1","title":"CFO","department":"Accounting","city":"Boston, MA","officePhone":"617-000-0003","cellPhone":"781-000-0003","email":"elee@fakemail.com","picture":"eugene_lee.jpg","managerFirstName":"James","managerLastName":"King","reportCount":"0"}}';

var data = JSON.parse(obj);
console.log(data.item);
```

Comment: It produces the following:SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at controllers.js:14
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:29132)
    at ionic.bundle.js:29148
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:30216)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30508)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:24829)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:25027)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (ionic.bundle.js:24968)

Comment: I am not sure about your code but you can see in my answer .. regarding that part of code